# Does spring-boot container create a pool of @service annotated classes or is it handled differently?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lifecycle

I was going through some spring-boot documentation and a little bit puzzled about the application/service lifecylce. First of all I didn't find some documentation resource with some fancy pictures that would explain how general lifecycle works (so maybe you can provide me with some material).

Furthermore I'm wondering what is really happening when I annotate one of my classes with @Service. Is there a pool of this service created and then the DI container injects instances of that pool in case they are needed? Can I control the amount of instances in that pool?

From good old Java EE I know the concept of stateless EJB that works like that (meaning a pool of EJBs is created) and there you can configure the amount of instances.
Any input welcome (especially links to further documentation material)

Comment: Spring beans are typically singleton (i.e. on instance in the context) unless specified to be otherwise.

Comment: @Taylor: This means that any field that you define on class level and that is written to is a potential issue as soon as you have several calls to the service right (I mean that's a standard singleton issue)?

Comment: Yup, they should be stateless.

Comment: Ok I see. Let's say you want to have some state in there, is the @Scope("prototype") annotation an option? I mean to me it looks like it's just acting like new operator, but done by DI container or is there some caveat with that

Comment: `@Scope("prototype")` is probably not going to work, it creates a new instance per injection.  If you inject a prototype scoped bean into a singleton bean, the prototype bean is still just one instance per app context.  You can look into request scoped beans https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-request

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I got it, interesting enough that it works that way, seems like I was a little too biased by Java EE beans, but it's always good to learn something new :) Another option that I see is to have both the controller class and the service class annotated with @Scope("prototype"), by that I overcome the scenario that you described above. If you but this info to an answer I would accept it ;)

Comment: Not sure that would work, since the controller is retrieved from context once by MVC plumbing, so you'd still have a de facto singleton controller and service